# django-pgcrypto: AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'SubfieldBase'

Tags: django, pgcrypto

I am trying to add django-pgcrypto to my django project but I am getting an error message:

```
class EncryptedTextField (six.with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, BaseEncryptedField)):
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'SubfieldBase'
```

Do you have any advice on how this could be fixed? I am using django 1.10 and python 3.5

Comment: You must be using an old version of django-pgcrypto - the latest 1.4.0 has fixed this, see https://github.com/dcwatson/django-pgcrypto/commit/9cf7c2948a341ca5c5e4beaec15c5bed00e85dfb.

Comment: I just did a pip3 install. I'll install 1.4.0. Cheers